# ¿Cómo hacer que un if muestre una cosa u otra en Django?

Tags: python, django

Estoy haciendo una página que contiene un sistema de login. En la página normal el navbar aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y una vez iniciada la sesión, quiero que aparezca una opción de cerrar la sesión.
 ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Este es el código del nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
<div class="container">
  {% load static %}
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand pr-5" style="border-right: 1px solid #efefef;" href="{% url "inicio" %}">
      <img src="{% static 'img/logo_muni.png' %}" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top"/>
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "historia" %}">Historia</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "autoridades" %}">Autoridades</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "entidades" %}">Entidades importantes</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "contacto" %}">Contacto</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "login" %}">Iniciar Sesión</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pongo un ejemplo de como yo lo haria:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1> Si ves esto eres un usuario autenticado. <h1>

    <form action="logout">
        <button type="submit">Logout</button>
    </form>

    {% if user.is_superuser %}
        <h1> Si ves esto eres un super usuario autenticado. <h1>

        <form action="logout">
            <button type="submit">Logout</button>
        </form>

{% else %}
    <h1> Autentícate por favor. </h1>

{% endif %}
```

Por cierto tu pregunta no es sobre Django, en realidad es sobre Jinja2. Acá te dejo el [link](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) a la documentación.

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo habia encontrado un foro en google que ponia exactamente lo mismo!